# How do I center my numerous paragraphs while using display: block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm building a portfolio website, and so I have a Heading on my About page and then some paragraphs.

Essentially, what I want to do is have the Heading and all Pargraphs centered in the middle of the page, and the text to wrap whenever there is less screen space, hence display: block, which will make it more responsive.

Previously, I had every single line in a new Paragraph Tag, making it nicer to read rather than it taking up the whole screen. This made it look odd on mobile, so I'm now using "display: block" (CSS) on all Paragraph Tags, which automatically wraps the text when there is less screen space.

However, I am now unable to center these paragraphs, and when using absolutecenter, this makes the paragraphs overlap each other. How should I go about this?

Here is the simplified block of HTML for the Page (barring the Nav Bar).

```
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="introToCam">
                <h1 id="centerHeading"> <b>About Me</b></h1>
                <p class="mb-5 pb-5 mt-3">
                    Text About Me
                </p>

                <br><br>    

                <p class="mb-5 pb-5 mt-3">
                    More Text About Me
                </p>

                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS for the Paragraph Tags.

```
p{
    display: block;
    max-width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Paragraphs are `display: block` by default

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xxBGLww?editors=1100

Comment: I've just tried removing the ```display: block``` and re-added the absolutecenter, the paragraphs now overlap each other.

Comment: Then don't use `absolutecenter`... it's not necessary. `text-align: center` is what you need. I assume there is a Bootstrap class that does that for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to provided code, to get required result to make paragraph tags centered in page, the CSS rule "margin: auto;" should be used as follows:

```
p {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: The answer has been edited to remove CSS rule "display: block;" because it is not required for <p> tag, which is block-level element, that is, it uses "display: block;" by default.